First Component of type
What library can I use to find a first AWT component of a certain type? It's likely such a method has been written long ago. I need it for tests of my Swing GUI
If I can specify whether the search should be depth-first or breadth-first, it would be splendid
// my depth-first implementation
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends Component> Optional<T> findChildByType(Container container, Class<T> childType) {
        for (Component component : container.getComponents()) {
            if (childType.isInstance(component))
                return Optional.of((T) component);
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                Optional<T> childByType = findChildByType((Container) component, childType);
                if (childByType.isPresent()) return childByType;
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

